# How can we get Spyder to pause execution after an error has occurred?

Tags: python, spyder

I'm debugging a program, and I would like it if Spyder could pause execution at an error. [I had read previously](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/PUjT5K95UlY) that this can be done without breakpoints by just running scripts in Debug mode, but that isn't working for me.

Eg, when I run the following script in Debug mode in Spyder, it just errors out at the index out of range exception without giving me any opportunity in ipdb to play with the variables.

```
import numpy as np   

A = np.random.randn(5)

A[7] = 8 #IndexError
```

More specifically, when I start debug, it starts me at the first line, then when I press Continue, execution proceeds all the way through line 3 without giving me a chance to inspect the workspace before execution exits.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I guess that if you launch your script under the "Run" > "Configuration per file" window and check "Directly enter debugging when errors appear" you get what you need. You should then run the script normally (not in debug mode).

Comment: This does not work for me! (Spyder Spyder 4.0.0rc3  and Spyder 3 as well)

Comment: Mine neither. Spyder 4.1.1

Comment: Tools --> Preferences (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P) --> Run --> "Directly enter debugging when errors appear". @mdgm 's instructions are on a per-file basis.

Comment: Works in spyder 5.3

Answer (score -3):

you need to add a breakpoint in your code, after start your debug mode, it will stop at the line where your break point ocurrs. Then, don't press continue, on the right of continue button there is a button that allow you to execute current line. It will execute your code in current line and move your breakpoint into next line. So you can check your code line by line.